# How can I map a function to apply to only certain rows in a data frame?

Tags: r, purrr

I have a function that I want to iterate over only certain rows of my dataset, and then save the results in a variable in the dataset.

So for example say I have this set up:

```
library(tidyverse)

add_one <- function(vector, x_id){
  return(vector[x_id] + 1)
}

test <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(1,2,3,4), run_on = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))
test
```

So the test data frame looks like:

```
>  x y run_on
>1 1 1   TRUE
>2 2 2  FALSE
>3 3 3   TRUE
>4 4 4  FALSE
```

So what I want to do is iterate over the dataframe and set the y column to be the result of applying the function add_one() to the x column for just the rows where run_on is TRUE. I want the end result to look like this:

```
>  x y run_on
>1 1 2   TRUE
>2 2 2  FALSE
>3 3 4   TRUE
>4 4 4  FALSE
```

I have been able to iterate the function over all of the rows using apply(). So for example:

```
test$y <- apply(test,1,add_one,x_id = 1)
test

>  x y run_on
>1 1 2   TRUE
>2 2 3  FALSE
>3 3 4   TRUE
>4 4 5  FALSE
```

But this also applies the function to rows 2 and 4, which I do not want. I suspect there may be some way to do this using versions of the map() functions from ::purrr, which is why I tagged this post as such.

In reality, I am using this kind of procedure to repeatedly iterate over a large dataset multiple times, so I need it to be done automatically and cleanly. Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I managed to find a solution. Some of the solutions offered here did work in my toy example but did not extend to the more complex function I was actually using. Ultimately what worked was something similar to what tmfmnk suggested. I  just wrapped the original function inside another function that included an if statement to determine whether or not to apply the original function. So to extend my toy example, my solution looks like this:

```
add_one_if <- function(vector, x_id, y_id, run_on_id){
    if(vector[run_on_id]){
        return(add_one(vector,x_id))}
    else{
        return(vector[x_id])
    }
}

test$y <- apply(test, 1, add_one_if, x_id = 1, y_id = 2, run_on_id = 3)
```

It seems a little convoluted, but it worked for me and is reproducible and reliable in the way I need it to be.

Comment: `with(test, y + run_on)` ;)

Comment: This is a clever solution if jcr is really only about adding one to a column. However, it sounds like this is just an example, in which case this won't generalize to other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do:

```
add_one <- function(data, vector, x_id, n, is.true = c(TRUE, FALSE)) {  
 if (is.true) {
  return(data[[vector]] + (data[[x_id]]) * n)
 } else {
  return(data[[vector]] + (!data[[x_id]]) * n)
 }
}   

add_one(test, vector = "y", x_id = "run_on", 1, is.true = TRUE)

[1] 2 2 4 4

add_one(test, vector = "y", x_id = "run_on", 5, is.true = FALSE)

[1] 1 7 3 9
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be that your real case is more complicated than allowed by this, but why not just use ifelse?

```
test$y <- ifelse(test$run_on,add_one(test,x),y)
```

Or even:

```
test$y[test$run_on]<-add_one(test[run_on,],x)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work because the columns of y and run_on are not objects in the r environment -- they are only in the dataframe. As a base:: function, ifelse() isn't smart enough to figure that out and returns an error to the tune of `object 'y' not found`

Comment: Can't test it right now, but won't test$y work in that situation then? Also, what about the second option?

Answer (score 1):

You won't need to use `purrr` until you are applying the same function to multiple columns. Since you want to modify only *one* column, but based on a condition you can use `mutate()` + `case_when()`.

```
mutate(test, y = case_when(run_on ~ add_one(y),
                           !run_on ~ y))
#>   x y run_on
#> 1 1 2   TRUE
#> 2 2 2  FALSE
#> 3 3 4   TRUE
#> 4 4 4  FALSE
```